# Magento 2, too many redirects. All browsers, frontend and backend

Tags: magento2, redirect, ssl

I've scoured through numerous threads on this subject and tried everything that was pertinent to my situation to no avail.

I have SSL enabled.  Everything was working fine until I edited one of the base_url's via command line.  However upon changing it back I now get the redirects error and have been battling with it for an entire day now.

Here are my core_config_value web values.

```
      1  | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_url         | http://www.newmillsoutlet.co.uk/
      59 | default |        0 | web/default/cms_home_page     | home                            
     123 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_static_url  | NULL                              
     124 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_media_url   | NULL                             
     125 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_url           | https://www.newmillsoutlet.co.uk/ 
     126 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_static_url    | NULL                              
     127 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_media_url     | NULL                              
     128 | default |        0 | web/cookie/cookie_path        | NULL                              
     129 | default |        0 | web/cookie/cookie_domain      | https://www.newmillsoutlet.co.uk/ 
     130 | default |        0 | web/cookie/cookie_httponly    | 1                                 
     426 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_link_url    | https://www.newmillsoutlet.co.uk/ 
     427 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_link_url      | https://www.newmillsoutlet.co.uk/ 
     428 | default |        0 | web/secure/use_in_frontend    | 1                                 
     429 | default |        0 | web/cookie/cookie_restriction | 0                                 
     487 | default |        0 | web/secure/use_in_adminhtml   | 1
```

I've cleared all the cache folders, restarted apache2.  But nothing seems to make any difference.  I just get the redirects error consistently.

Also using http://www.redirect-checker.org/ I can see that without the www. I get a 200 OK yet if I use www it is throwing the too many redirects error.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Thanks

*** UPDATE 1 ***

The frontend now loads fine, no issues there.  My problem now is that I cannot access the backend/admin page.  It gives the following error after throwing an exception:

Front Controller Reached 100 Router Match Iterations.

Again I've had a good look through SE for any information but cannot find anything which relates to me exact issue.

Comment: please check in core_config_data that web/seo/use_rewrites 's value is 1

Comment: Hi Rutvee, I've checked for web/seo/use_rewrites but cannot find that value anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Insert in your core_config_data tabel below data and  check after clearing cache and cookie

> INSERT INTO `core_config_data` ( `scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES
>   ( 'default', 0, 'web/seo/use_rewrites', '1')

you can do this by admin marketing->url rewrite option but your admin currently not working So insert manually and check.

```
       array('config_id' => '3','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' =>'web/unsecure/base_url','value' => 'http://www.newmillsoutlet.co.uk/'),
    array('config_id' => '4','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/secure/base_url','value' => 'http://www.newmillsoutlet.co.uk/'),
    array('config_id' => '240','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/url/use_store','value' => '1'),
    array('config_id' => '241','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/url/redirect_to_base','value' => '1'),
    array('config_id' => '242','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/seo/use_rewrites','value' => '1'),
    array('config_id' => '243','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/unsecure/base_link_url','value' => '{{unsecure_base_url}}'),
    array('config_id' => '244','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/unsecure/base_skin_url','value' => '{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/'),
    array('config_id' => '245','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/unsecure/base_media_url','value' => '{{unsecure_base_url}}/media/'),
    array('config_id' => '246','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/unsecure/base_js_url','value' => '{{unsecure_base_url}}js/'),
    array('config_id' => '247','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/secure/base_link_url','value' => '{{secure_base_url}}'),
    array('config_id' => '248','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/secure/base_skin_url','value' => '{{secure_base_url}}skin/'),
    array('config_id' => '249','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/secure/base_media_url','value' => '{{secure_base_url}}/media/'),
    array('config_id' => '250','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/secure/base_js_url','value' => '{{secure_base_url}}js/'),
    array('config_id' => '251','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/secure/use_in_frontend','value' => '0'),
    array('config_id' => '252','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/secure/use_in_adminhtml','value' => '0'),
    array('config_id' => '253','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/secure/offloader_header','value' => 'SSL_OFFLOADED'),
    array('config_id' => '254','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/default/front','value' => 'cms'),
    array('config_id' => '255','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/default/cms_home_page','value' => 'home'),
    array('config_id' => '256','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/default/no_route','value' => 'cms/index/noRoute'),
    array('config_id' => '257','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/default/cms_no_route','value' => 'no-route'),
    array('config_id' => '258','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/default/cms_no_cookies','value' => 'enable-cookies'),
    array('config_id' => '259','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/default/show_cms_breadcrumbs','value' => '1'),
    array('config_id' => '260','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/polls/poll_check_by_ip','value' => '0'),
    array('config_id' => '261','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/cookie/cookie_lifetime','value' => '36000000'),
    array('config_id' => '262','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/cookie/cookie_path','value' => NULL),
    array('config_id' => '263','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/cookie/cookie_domain','value' => NULL),
    array('config_id' => '264','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/cookie/cookie_httponly','value' => '1'),
    array('config_id' => '265','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/session/use_remote_addr','value' => '0'),
    array('config_id' => '266','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/session/use_http_via','value' => '0'),
    array('config_id' => '267','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/session/use_http_x_forwarded_for','value' => '0'),
    array('config_id' => '268','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/session/use_http_user_agent','value' => '0'),
    array('config_id' => '269','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/session/use_frontend_sid','value' => '0'),
    array('config_id' => '270','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/browser_capabilities/cookies','value' => '1'),
    array('config_id' => '271','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/browser_capabilities/javascript','value' => '1'),
    array('config_id' => '1334','scope' => 'default','scope_id' => '0','path' => 'web/cookie/cookie_restriction','value' => '0')
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm now getting a 404 page not found on the main shop page and the too many redirects error if I add /admin to the URL. If I add /index.php to the shop page it now displays, but I cannot click on any links.

Comment: @dispatj please check in your core_config_data table all config value are set. i have edited in my ans

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify I am using SSL so should the http be https instead?

Comment: yes you can set according like it

Comment: I seem to be missing quite a few of those config values.  I will add them in now.

Comment: I've added in the missing config values, now after clearing cache it is still showing 404 page not found.  If I add /index.php it then adds /default onto the URL and shows the too many redirects error again

Comment: I'm also noticing I can load the homepage using by omitting the www. however if I try to click any links they result in the too many redirects error.  I also cannot load /admin without the too many redirects error

Comment: Are you using nginx server?

Comment: I am using apache2 on google cloud platform.

Comment: Ok so good news, I have now managed to get the store working and the links also work.  Thanks so much for your help with this.  My issue now is I get an exception when trying to visit /admin.  The error in the report file is this:

Front controller reached 100 router match iterations.  

Have you ever come across this before?

Comment: @dispatj please refer this link may be it can help you https://github.com/convenient/magento-ce-ee-config-corruption-bug#the-fix
And please accept answer if you will reach to your answer.
Thank you so much!!

Comment: It looks like that is for Magento 1.9? I am using Magento 2 :)

Answer (score 0):

Create Seperate Virtualhost for backend and frontend and it will work fine.